# Asynchronous Callback in NSOperation inside of NSOperationQueue is never called

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, callback, queue

I need to chain together several `NSOperation`s that do network calls in one `NSOperationQueue` and then wait for all to be completed.

I'm adding all of the `NSOperation`s to my `NSOperationQueue` and then call `operationQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()`. This works, but it waits indefinitely, as the callbacks in the `NSOperations`, that set the operation's state to 'finished', get never called.

I'm using the following `NSOperation` subclass:

```
class ConcurrentOperation: NSOperation
{
    enum State: String
    {
        case Ready, Executing, Finished

        private var keyPath: String
        {
            return "is" + self.rawValue
        }
    }

    var state: State = State.Ready {
        willSet (newValue)
        {
            self.willChangeValueForKey(newValue.keyPath)
            self.willChangeValueForKey(self.state.keyPath)
        }

        didSet
        {
            self.didChangeValueForKey(oldValue.keyPath)
            self.didChangeValueForKey(self.state.keyPath)
        }
    }
}

extension ConcurrentOperation
{
    override var ready: Bool {
        return super.ready && self.state == .Ready
    }

    override var executing: Bool {
        return self.state == .Executing
    }

    override var finished: Bool {
        return self.state == .Finished
    }

    override var concurrent: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var asynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension ConcurrentOperation
{
    override func start()
    {
        if self.cancelled
        {
            self.state = .Finished
            return
        }

        self.state = .Executing
        self.main()
    }

    override func cancel()
    {
        self.state = .Finished
    }
}
```

This is based on a Raywenderlich Tutorial and https://gist.github.com/calebd/93fa347397cec5f88233 .

What this should do is tell the NSOperationQueue that only when the `main()` method in a subclass of `ConcurrentOperation` sets the state to `.Finished` it is completed. **And this is also fulfilled by the operation.**

*However*, If I construct the following `main()` method in such a `ConcurrentOperation` subclass, the `NSOperationQueue` never stops as the **asynchronous part is never called**:

```
override func main()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        sleep(1)
        self.state = .Finished  // never called!
    })
}
```

The problem is the same with a Firebase-Query Callback that I use in my app.

I tried to override the `concurrent: Bool` property and return `true`, but that doesn't fix it neither.

How can I accomplish that asynchronous tasks are actually executed in my `ConcurrentOperation` subclass' `main()` method?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on the main queue?  If so, then you have blocked the main queue and the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` code doesn't get a chance to execute

Comment: I am. Even though I was doing that in a `dispatch_async(_,_)` block, it did block the main queue. You're awesome! Thank you! If you write a regular answer to my question, I'll mark it as correct. @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on the main queue then you will block the main queue. Once the main queue is blocked the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),` won't be able to execute as you have created a deadlock;  The task that needs to execute to unblock the main queue has been dispatched on the blocked main queue, so it will never run and can never run.

You need to dispatch the `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on its own queue.